# Setting of environment variables using shell script on Red Hat

Tags: bash, environment-variables, redhat

I created a shell script on Red Hat to set some environment variables:

```
#Exporting variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/soft/java8/jdk1.8.0_92
echo JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
echo JRE_HOME=$JRE_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
echo PATH=$PATH
```

Result as expected:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/soft/java8/jdk1.8.0_92
JRE_HOME=/usr/soft/java8/jdk1.8.0_92/jre
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/soft/java8/jdk1.8.0_92/bin
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
java -version
```

However environment variables wasn't set. After running java -version command I've got

```
 java -version
 -bash: java: command not found message.
```

end

```
 echo $JAVA_HOME
```

returned just empty line.

How to write proper shell script to set environment variables on Redhat os?

Thanks for help.

Comment: How did you use the script.  If it was run in a subshell (normal if you just run it), it set the environment variables in *that* shell and not your interactive shell.  You probably want to learn about the `source` command, which will eval a script in the current shell rather than running in a subshell.

Comment: I running my script in a Putty shell that is on my local machine (external shell concerning to redhat it self). I suppose it is a subshell - sorry for my unknowledge. I guess it might be a reason. Thanks for the hint. Will search for how to run a script using **subshell** . Thanks dude.

Comment: So, as MAP was mentioned above, there is 'source' command, that executes the content of the file passed as argument, in the current shell.